# Concatinate Variable define in Dynamic Query

Tags: dynamicquery

I'm building a dynamic query. Inside it, I have declare variables. Now I want to concatenate this variable in my insert query

```
declare @qry nvarchar(MAX)
select @qry='Declare @var1 nvarchar(10); set @var1 =''abcd''
insert into mytable (col1) values ('+@var1+')'
```

When I execute this code it give me an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@var1".

But if I declare @var1 outside @qry then it works fine.I am having problem in concatenating the value of variable.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. The context of execution of Dynamic query is different from the outer script.

this will work

```
declare @qry nvarchar(MAX)
Declare @var1 nvarchar(10); 
set @var1 ='abcd'
select @qry='insert into mytable (col1) values ('+@var1+')'
```